# Run stored procedure passing a parameter from Batch file

Tags: batch-file, stored-procedures, sqlcmd

I have the below in a batch file and can not seem to get the `%1` value to pass to the stored procedure.  I have tried many combinations and searches without success.  Can someone tell me how to format the command to pass that value to the stored procedure.  I know the value is making it there because of the echo.  The value is like such `0055731`.  thanks for any help.

```
echo %1
pause   
sqlcmd -S Esserver\rsssql -d RSSIntegration -Q "exec sp_ImportSageOrders " & %1
```

Comment: Do you have a version that works using the value directly (instead of a parameter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this working by including the %1 parameters inside the double quotes and if more than one parameter then put a `,` between each.

Example as follows:

```
echo %1 %2
pause
sqlcmd -S Esserver\rsssql -d RSSIntegration -Q "exec sp_ImportSageOrders %1, %2"
```

Comment: That was it.  Thanks miltonb.  Unfortunately, I might of had it at one point but because the SP I was calling was not updated, to the one it needed to be, I thought I was doing something wrong.  Since I had tried couple dozen different combinations had no idea what to do anymore.  Thanks again!!!